# How to know if the solution is right?

Tags: recursion

The question is: f(0) = 3; f(1) = 5; f(n) = 3*f(n-1)-f(n-2)+17; I think my code is okay but I dont have any proof that my result is correct. the question is what is f(3) and f(20). For f(3) i got '99' and for f(20) i got '1469588013'. My concerns are that the jump from f(1) = 5 to f(3) = 99 is looking kinda weird...

- And in general how can I know that i am writing a correct code...not in terms of syntax but in results it returns?
- I have to use recursion and java has to be the language:)

This is my code

```
public class rekursion {
public static int reku(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 3;
    else if (n == 1) return 5;
    else return  3*(reku(n-1)) - reku(n-2) + 17;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reku(20));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm, translated to scala, gives me 69 for 3:

```
scala> def reku2 (n: Long) : Long ={
     |     if (n == 0L) 3 else 
     |     if (n == 1L) 5 else 
     |     3*(reku2 (n-1)) - reku2 (n-2) + 17L
     | }
reku2: (n: Long)Long

scala>  (1 to 20).foreach (x => println (reku (3, 5, x)))
5
21
11
69
-19
243
-283
1029
-1861
4965
-10531
25443
-57019
133365
-304405
704517
-1617715
3731283
-8584411
19778277
```

We can change it, to run up instead of down:

```
scala> def reku (lo: Long, hi: Long, target: Long) : Long = target match {
     |   case 0 => 3L
     |   case 1 => hi 
     |   case x => reku (hi, 3*lo - hi + 17, target - 1) 
     | }
reku: (lo: Long, hi: Long, target: Long)Long

(1 to 10).foreach (x => println (reku (3, 5, x)))
```

This will call the function only 1 time for each of the lower values, not 2, 4, ... times.

Note that using a Long gives us a little more fun, than Int. BigInteger would still be much better.